# How to store a date in SQLite?

Tags: database, sqlite, datetime

How do I store on a table a value date using the format `'yyyy -mm- dd'` ? because SQLITE does not have a specific type to store this kind of value ?

Example of use:

```
SELECT * FROM MySimpleTable
WHERE DeliveryDate between '1/11/2015' AND '6/11/2015'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To store:

```
 INSERT INTO YourSimpleTable (DeliveryDate) VALUES ('2015-01-11')
 INSERT INTO YourSimpleTable (DeliveryDate) VALUES ('2015-06-11')
```

To retrieve:

```
 SELECT * FROM YourSimpleTable WHERE DeliveryDate BETWEEN '2015-01-11' AND '2015-06-11'
```